# how to create MoveIt package for robot arm with gripper?

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic, gripper, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create moveit package for robot arm with gripper but it allows only to add one urdf (I have one urdf for the arm one urdf for the gripper)?
am working on UR5 arm and using  robotiq_85_gripper gripper!

I already followed tutorials showing how to create moveit packages only for the arm! but need for arm with installed gripper, any ideas?
thanks in advanced

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336567/how-to-create-moveit-package-for-robot-arm-with-gripper?/) by [Rony_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/38957/rony_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just create a new xacro file where you include the two urdfs,
something like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/ur10_robot.urdf.xacro" />

  <xacro:include filename="$(find robotiq_85_description)/urdf/robotiq_85_gripper.xacro" />

  </robot>
```

make sure to connect the first frame of the gripper with the last frame of the UR (should be tool0).
Once you load the new urdf with the setup assistant you can see graphically if you have succeeded.

---

Originally posted by [Alessio](https://answers.ros.org/users/29098/alessio/) with karma: 48 on 2019-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-02**:\

> make sure to connect the first frame of the gripper with the last frame of the UR (should be tool0).

actually, `tool0` is not meant for tool attachment, but only represents an "all zeros toolframe".

For the models in `ur_description`, the `ee_link` frame may be more appropriate. But be sure to check the orientation of that frame.

**Comment by [Rony_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/38957/rony_s/) on 2019-11-03**:
thanks @Alessio, tool0 was exactly the right link too

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-04**:
I'm repeating myself, but @Rony_s: `tool0` is *not* the right link to attach tools to.

It will be submitted at a later point, but see [Coordinate Frames for Serial Industrial Manipulators](http://gavanderhoorn.github.io/rep/rep-0199.html) for why `tool0` should not be used (specifically the [flange](http://gavanderhoorn.github.io/rep/rep-0199.html#flange) section (note that `ur_description` doesn't have `flange` frames yet, which is why I suggested using `ee_link`)).

**Comment by [Rony_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/38957/rony_s/) on 2019-11-05**:
@gvdhoorn you have right, tool0 in the case of having gripper is wrong, is found it should be wrist_3_link the last link connected to the gripper, but I think it also depends on how you configure the Moveit package too